# How I can find and change liferay AUI script?

Tags: javascript, liferay, document

I have this script in one of my jsps. Its used to preview the documents in liferay. My question is where to find the implementation of this function and can I change it in order to add additional things in the preview.. or to change something.

```
<aui:script use="liferay-preview">
    new Liferay.Preview(
        {
            actionContent: '#<portlet:namespace /><%= randomNamespace %>previewFileActions',
            baseImageURL: '<%= previewFileURL %>',
            boundingBox: '#<portlet:namespace /><%= randomNamespace %>previewFile',
            contentBox: '#<portlet:namespace /><%= randomNamespace %>previewFileContent',
            currentPreviewImage: '#<portlet:namespace /><%= randomNamespace %>previewFileImage',
            imageListContent: '#<portlet:namespace /><%= randomNamespace %>previewImagesContent',
            maxIndex: <%= previewFileCount %>,
            previewFileIndexNode: '#<portlet:namespace /><%= randomNamespace %>previewFileIndex',
            toolbar: '#<portlet:namespace /><%= randomNamespace %>previewToolbar'
        }
    ).render();
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 2):

How can you find this module?

- Download Liferay Sourcecode
- Search for "liferay-preview" in all *.js files

Where can you find this module?

- [preview.js](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/js/liferay/preview.js)

Can you change it?

- Yes